# A form for filtering data is Get or Post

Tags: asp.net-mvc, rest

Just quick question,

`MVC` form used for retrieving filtered data,

ideally, would this be classed as a Get or Post in Restful terms?

Comment: Based on form `Method` attribute you set, Default is `GET`

Answer (score 0):

If You are asking about form methods then you need to do::

For POST=>

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("MainDocumentSave", "Document", FormMethod.Post, new { @class="MainForm"}))
{

//Form data
}
```

&

For GET=>

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("MainDocumentSave", "Document", FormMethod.Get, new { @class="MainForm"}))
{

//Form data
}
```

Answer (score 0):

POST is for modifying resources/state on the server. GET is for getting resources from the server. Retrieving filtered data should, according to REST, be a GET, not a POST.